# "Knowledge of" vs. "knowledge on"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> She tried to figure out how much knowledge my class had **of** the real Pocahontas.

Should I use *of* or *on* there?

Answer (score 2):

It could also be that "knowledge of" goes with a person or shows one's familiarity with someone or something (cf. the verb *kennen* in German) and "knowledge on" or "knowledge about" (cf. the verb *wissen* in German) goes with a field of study or a broad subject where one's personal attachment to it is irrelevant.

It also seems that "knowledge about" could be used in either case; it's just a longer form that may not be desired if someone's trying to write poetic verse or a terse newspaper headline, for example.

Comment: Nice answer! If you have any references to support it, please [edit] them in so that we can upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to look at this would be to consider what one is trying to convey.

This could also read "*knowledge my class had **concerning** the real Pocahontas.*" The word *concerning* often takes the genitive case in Greek and Latin, which relates to the word *of*. However, the expression "*on the real Pocahontas*" would take the ablative case in Latin and would not coincide with *concerning*. Therefore, the sentence

> She tried to figure out how much knowledge my class had **of** the
>   real Pocahontas.

is more likely to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The preposition *of* is generally used with *[knowledge](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/knowledge)*: "knowledge of (something)".

> her considerable knowledge of antiques
> he denied all knowledge of the incidents

However, it is important to note here that the question relates not to some personal acquaintance with Pocahontas ("knowledge of Pocahontas"), but an understanding of the concept ("knowledge **on** Pocahontas").

If the pupils have studied and understood the story, they would have such an understanding.

> Without a credible data sharing mechanism, building strategic knowledge **on** climate change is virtually impossible.
> General Knowledge **on** the Use of Medicines

We need to use the preposition ***on*** in the example sentence.

> She tried to figure out how much knowledge my class had **on** the real Pocahontas.

Comment: I don't believe this distinction. Knowledge *on* a subject is simply non-standard - it doesn't carry some special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Only knowledge *of* and *about* are listed in the *Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English*. Hence, I think they are better.

> MEANINGS
>
> 1.the information, skills, and understanding that you have gained through learning or experience
>   • He did not have much knowledge of American history.
>
> [+ about]
>   • the need to increase knowledge about birth control

Comment: if you mean the fact that "*when you know about a particular situation or event, or the information you have about it*", there's only *about*.